# Contacts LDAP Account on 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: mail.app, macos, contacts, ldap

I am trying to set up an **LDAP** account for the **Contacts** application in the **10.11 (El Capitan) OS X** version. I need it, for example, to be able to autocomplete addresses via the **Mail** application.

I've been using this feature in older versions without problems, but with **10.11** I am unable to retrieve contacts from the server. Even on 10.11.3 - connecting to an OpenLDAP 2.4 server or to Active Directory 2008 R2 using a "formal" dn, login & password fails.

In this version the setup can be done vie the **Internet Accounts** at the **System Preferences** pane or directly in the **Contacts** app. The first nuisance is that the password can only be entered once the account has been enabled on the preferences on the **Contacts** app. Having found this, the new account only appears after restarting the app, and then, searching anything always returns an empty set.

The information to connect to the server (host, user dn, password, base...) is valid and works in previous releases. Doing an **ldapsearch** works fine as it does configuring the LDAP contacts in **Thunderbird** in OS X. It seems to me that it is related to the OS.

Is this a bug or is there a procedure to connect to LDAP?

Comment: What OS and version is your LDAP server? What OS and version is your user account client on?

Comment: I've tried it against an OpenLDAP 2.4 server, and also against Active Directory 2008 R2 using a "formal" dn, login & password... You name it.

Comment: Still not working in version **10.11.3**...

Comment: I've bumped this with an edit, but you might need to contact Apple for guidance - their engineering team is very good about getting to the bottom of things like this, but you might have to use a Mac covered with AppleCare to get them on the hook for free support. A paid incident might run you $50 or so if you aren't covered by any support agreements yet.

Comment: I filed a bug with Apple.  My bug was marked as a duplicate of bug 21707365.  Today (2017-02-21) I was notified that the original bug was "recently closed."

Comment: @JoePallas Me too, I tried filing a bug. I even got to talk to the engineers at Apple. Their official response was that it had to do with old crypto-cyphers that had been dumped in recent versions of the OS. It made little sense to me, though... I stopped trying... :-(

Answer (score 2):

I had checked network packets with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and found that OSX 10.11 and 10.11.1 do not send bindRequest to LDAP server (only searchRequest and unbindRequest), nevertheless authenticate method was configured as 'simple authentication'.
This is bug.

Comment: Interesting. I'm having the same problem: what worked before suddenly no longer works. I don't need a login and password. I'm also finding that when I try to set the port # to 389, it always reverts to "Auto"

What's weird is that a user at my university claims that LDAP lookups work for him in 10.11.1.

Answer (score 1):

same here.  and I checked the ldap server, the log shows it never be connected. it may be the 10.11 problem

Comment: I see this as +1 and saying its a bug. This answer could be wrong, but it clearly is an answer.